# How we can use MAGTEK credit card swiper with chrome or firefox?

Tags: credit-card

Right now USB Credit card swipers are supported with IE only as they are using ActiveX controls. Is it possible to use them with chrome or firefox. I have MAGTEK Swiper.

Thanks in advance for all your help

Answer (score 3):

While this is late, it should work for FireFox Windows, at least.

MagTek has a signed java applet that interfaces with the swipe device.  I have used this in my application, but Chrome recently dropped java applet support, so I'm looking for a new solution for Chrome, too.

http://www.magtek.com/support/documentation/download_software.asp (search the text for JMSR)

```
<div class="javapplet">
<object type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6" height="3" width="30">
    <param name="code" value="JMTCardReader.class" />
    <param name="archive" value="JMTCardReader.jar" />
    <param name="cache_option" value="No">
    <param name="classloader_cache" value="true">
    <!-- param name="java_arguments" value="-Djnlp.packEnabled=true"/ -->
    Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
</object>
</div>
```

You add your own javascript to handle the results of a swipe, set form input values, etc.  The example javascript is nice place to start.  mtjmsr.js and mtjmsr.html show what has been collected from a card swipe.

I use a stylesheet to "hide" the javaapplet div by making the text the same color as the background.  I can see the results by selecting in that area if needed.

UPDATE:  9/2/2016
MagTek has created, essentially, a web server host to install on indivivual PCs that are connected to a card reader such as their eDynamo reader.  This allows a browser page on the individual's computer to communicate through javascript to the reader and get card information.
I have used the Windows version, I think they may have versions for other OSs, too.

UPDATE Nov 10, 2016

**Solved for our organization**

I created a Chrome extension that has the rights to communicate with the MagTek server mentioned above.
I don't think I am allowed to share the code, but the process is:

- The extension is a background process and a content process.
- The content process gets installed in a sandbox on pages allowed in its manifest.  It adds an event listener to a button known to be on our card-swipe page.
- User clicks the known button.
- Extension handles the event - asks the background process to initiate a card swipe and obtain the card data.
- The content process prepares a form submit using the card data (since we are sending our data to PayPal).  It could also populate known inputs on the page.

This is working for us now with both MagTek encrypting readers and older non-encrypting readers.

I hope this is clear and useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of credit card swipers but I think you've probably answered your own question. If they aren't supported on other browsers and require ActiveX then they won't work. That said there are addons like [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab/) for FF that will make a tab use IE but this probably isn't very practical as switching at the checkout stage will probably empty your basket.

I did see [ActiveX for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/activex-for-chrome/lgllffgicojgllpmdbemgglaponefajn?hl=en) when I searched the Chrome Web Store. But I've not tired it and don't know if it is trustworthy. It does have 567 votes with a 4.5 star rating.

If you try one of my suggestions, I'd love to hear how you get on.

Comment: I have tried that AcitveXfor Chorome but it is not either compatible with my swiper or have some flaw in working I guess. Thanks for your time